# MIME mail is not showing some pdf and .doc attachments

Tags: attachment, mime

Hello this is my first post on this site.

Now i encountered a strange problem with MIME. I am working on writing emlx mail files.
(objective c, cocoa)
now i have no problem with showing images in mails. the problems is that half of my .doc and pdf attachments don't show in the message.

An formatting example.

```
MessageLength in Bytes(i.e 8556)

From: some@email
To: some@email2
Subject: mailsubject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="somerandomgeneratedstring"

--somerandomgeneratedstring
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Body Text(not html body)

--somerandomgeneratedstring
Content-Type: application/msword; name="somefile.doc"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somefile.doc"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

[base64 encoded data]

--somerandomgeneratedstring--

PlistStructure
```

The text body is always displayed properly. The problem is that some text file attachments like .doc and pdf are not displayed, i run the same code for multiple text files and some work and some do not i have no clue why. all pictures work. 
The thing i don't get is if i use the same data that wont work for MIME and write is as a file to my desktop the file is displayed properly.

Is there something i am missing ? Is there something i have to take care of when encoding such files in base64 ? if so why do some files work and others dont ?(source is in binary format, i encode is using nsdata base64encoding in Xcode)
I have gone trough the mime documentation multiple times and i cant seem so find a solution.
Can anyone please give me some tips or suggestions ?

EDIT: omg i forgot about this, The problem was that i had a problem with the first line, length in bytes, after i fixed that it worked. Sorry for wasting time :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the blank line between the top-level `MIME-Version` and `Content-Type` headers.  MIME headers and body are separated by a blank line, so your `Content-Type` is effectively ignored as a header and treated as body content instead.

```
From: some@email
To: some@email2
Subject: mailsubject
MIME-Version: 1.0
                    <-- get rid of this blank line
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="somerandomgeneratedstring"
```

**Update**: since this problem is not a factor anymore, the only remaining factor you have not shown yet is the actual base64 data.  It is likely malformed in some way that is preventing proper decoding.  Everything else you have shown is accurate.

Comment: Sorry i just wrote it wrong here, there is no blank line in my code. the error is not i formating. it will show some .doc files but does not show others, the only difference is in the base64 endoded data and filename.

Comment: i replaced all body with (this is a random body) and the files are showing now, i have an error within the body. ill post the solution once i certain what it is.